# Sending Data From Android To Server with JSON data

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying sending data from Android application to web server. My android application is working successfully.However php code have problems.

```
<?php
$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
echo "JSON: \n";
var_dump($json);
echo "\n\n";

$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo "Array: \n";
var_dump($data);
echo "\n\n";

$name = $data['name'];
$pos = $data['position'];
echo "Result: \n";
echo "Name     : ".$name."\n Position : ".$pos; 
?>
```

**Errors:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_JSON in C:\wamp\www\jsonTest.php on line 2
( line 2 : $json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON']; )
```

I couldn't find these problems reason. Can you help me ?
( note: I am using wamp server )

Here is the relevant Android source:

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header 
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("10.0.2.2:90/jsonTest.php";); 

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
try { 
    json.put("name", "flower"); 
    json.put("position", "student"); 
    JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray(); 
    postjson.put(json); 
    httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
    httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson); 
    System.out.print(json); 
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 

    if(response != null)
    {
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        try {
        is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    text = sb.toString();
    }
    tv.setText(text);

}catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

This code works successfully on android side(no error). But php side has problems..
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't where your JSON is:

```
$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
```

You possibly meant:

```
$json = $_POST['HTTP_JSON'];
```

Where `HTTP_JSON` is the POST variable name you gave to your JSON in your Android app.

The rest of the errors stem from the fact that `json_decode` is failing because you're not successfully reading the JSON data from the request. You can check the response of `json_decode` to check if it was successful as follows:

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
if( $data === NULL)
{
    exit( 'Could not decode JSON');
}
```

Finally, passing `true` as the second parameter to `json_encode` means it will return an associative array, so you'd access elements like so:

```
$name = $data['name'];
$pos = $data['position'];
```

Make sure you [read the docs](http://us.php.net/json_decode) for json_encode so you understand what it's doing.

**Edit:** Your problem is that you're accessing the `$_POST` parameter by the wrong name. You should be using:

```
$json = $_POST['jsonpost'];
```

Since the following line names the parameter "jsonpost":

```
httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I used $_POST instead of $_SERVER but the same error : Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_JSON in C:\wamp\www\jsonTest.php on line 3.

Comment: Your PHP script isn't picking up the JSON data... Post the relevant sections of Android code where you're sending the JSON to the server.

Comment: One part of the code :                                                  // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:90/jsonTest.php");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
json.put("name", "Irem");
json.put("position", "student");

JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
postjson.put(json);
httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);
System.out.print(json);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: I also tried your last solution. But the error didn't change. Can the wamp server cause of this problem ?

Comment: @iremce - No, WAMP shouldn't make a difference. Let me check one of my Android projects and see if you're doing something wrong on the client side.

Comment: It looks like there's a few things wrong with your Android source code. I found this tutorial that should help: http://www.hdelossantos.com/2009/12/24/quick-and-easy-android-http-post-of-json-string/ . Following that tutorial, you'd pick up the JSON from `$_POST['jsonString']`.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know how the java client sends the request
I would try :

```
print_r($_SERVER);
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
```

To figure out how it does.

Answer (score 1):

try these lines:

```
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
     httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```