# Posting gps coordinates on php server from android phone

Tags: php, android, post, gps

What I am trying is I get my current location (the coordinates) and i want to post those coordinates on a server. I have made a server using WAMP. I have written php code and the code in java but its showing me error in the **POST** word. Please tell me if its correct or if i can modify it!!

PHP CODE

```
<?php
echo 'Hello, world!';
$json = $_GET['jsonpost'];//get the post you sent...
$data = json_decode($json); //decode the json formatted string...
print_r($data);
$id = $data->id;
$devid = $data->devid;
$latitude = $data->latitude;
$longitude = $data->longitude;
$service = $data->service;
$con = mysql_connect("","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("a5234826_ul", $con);
$devid = $_POST['devid']; 
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
echo "devid" +$devid;
echo "latitude" + $latitude;
echo "longitude" + $longitude; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `a5234826_ul`.`locations` (
`id` ,
`devid` ,
`latitude` ,
`longitude` ,
`service`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '$devid',  '$latitude',  '$longitude', '$service'  
)";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($variable);
```

?>

**EDITED**
LocationService.java

```
    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "lock");
    wl.acquire();
    context = this;
    final String who = intent.getStringExtra("who");
    final LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener(){

        // start location changed

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            double longitude = loc.getLongitude();


            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://.../serverFile.php");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();


            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String devid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

            String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\",\"devid\":\""+devid+"\"}}";




            try {  

                json.put("longitude", longitude);//place each of the strings as you did in postData method
                json.put("latitude", latitude);

                json.put("devid", devid);

                JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
                postjson.put(json);
                httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
                httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);     
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // for JSON retrieval:
                if(response != null)
                { 
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                try {
                is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                String jsonStr = sb.toString(); //take the string you built place in a string



                JSONObject rec = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String longitudecord = rec.getString("lon");
                    String latitudecord = rec.getString("lat");
                // ...
                }
                }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




            if (who.equals("me")){
                Intent i = new Intent(context.getPackageName()+".LocationReceived");
                i.putExtra("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
                i.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
                i.putExtra("accuracy", String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));
                context.sendBroadcast(i);
                Notification notif = new Notification();
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notif.tickerText = "Location Found!";
                notif.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notif.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TestLocatorActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
                notificationIntent.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
                notificationIntent.putExtra("accuracy", String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Location Found!", "Click to open.", contentIntent);
                nm.notify(0, notif);
            } else {
                SmsManager smsMan = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsMan.sendTextMessage(who, null, "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:"+latitude+","+longitude, null, null);
                smsMan.sendTextMessage(who, null, "Latitude: "+latitude+"\nLongitude: "+longitude, null, null);
            }
            locMan.removeUpdates(this);
            try {
                wl.release();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stopSelf();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){


        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            //Log.i(tag, "GPS IS ON");
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            switch(status) {
                case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        } };


    locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);

    return 2;
}

}
```

Comment: Getting error on the word POST...

Comment: @shadyyx Please see the edited part...? is it fine..?

Comment: I cannot run Your android code so I cannot say whether is it OK... What exactly is Your error message?

Comment: I tried...the code.. but the application is force closing...

Comment: Edited my answer, please read, think of what are You doing and try also to use http://www.google.com ...

Comment: please give read_phone_state permission into your androidmanifest.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem I can see here is that You are talking about `POST` but in Your android `LocationService` You are creating an `HttpGet` object:

```
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://.../serverFile.php");
```

and then from nowhere a `httpost` variable is used as `post`:

```
post.setHeader("json",json.toString());
post.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);
```

In PHP I'm not sure what are You trying to achieve by this:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
```

cos I'm sure there is no such index. Instead call

```
$_POST['jsonpost']; // <-- that is the parameter name from Your JAVA code...
```

or

```
$_GET['jsonpost']; // <-- that is the parameter name from Your JAVA code...
```

It almost looks like You COPY + PASTE the code from similar question here (**which this one should be a duplicate of!**): [Sending Data From Android To Server with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317553/sending-data-from-android-to-server-with-json-data) .

**EDIT :** OK, let's assume that Your android JAVA code is OK and You are sending data through GET. Then You will have to repair Your PHP - try this:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello, world!';

$json = $_GET['jsonpost']; // get the json you sent through GET...
$data = json_decode($json); // decode the json formatted string...

print_r($data); // print out the $data variable to see whether everything is OK...

$devid = $data->devid;
$longitude = $data->longitude;
$latitude = $data->latitude;

$con = mysql_connect("","","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());    
mysql_select_db("a5234826_ul", $con);

echo "devid" +$devid;
echo "latitude" + $latitude;
echo "longitude" + $longitude; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO  `a5234826_ul`.`locations` (
    `devid`,
    `latitude`,
    `longitude` 
) VALUES (
    '$Devid',
    '$latitude',  
    '$longitude'
);";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($variable);
```

You should proceed with the `print_r($data);` and see whether the data arrived and whether the JSON was decoded and also to see what properties it contains.

**EDIT 2 Due to posted logcat:** Did You read the error from the logcat? It is so clear!!! Programmer should of course understand what an error message is saying and should thing about what he is doing, not just copy+pasting pieces of code from somewhere without thinking of it... In Your manifest.xml You need to add a permision READ_PHONE_STATE - read about permissions here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html and about adding permissions to manifest.xml here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions.

Comment: Didnt copy paste it from there.. what should i exactly do.. could you help me in that... please.

Comment: Hey i edited few things... everythings working fine... but the coordinates and device id are not being posted...

Comment: OK then try to google this term: android post data [direct link](https://www.google.cz/#q=android+post+data&fp=1). Use google first, when no solution is found then ask here at SO...

Comment: I know this old post, but somebody should note that the above PHP code is vulnerable to SQL injection, which is a sizeable security issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php